# Calculate and format time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I execute the following command in SQL Server 2008 and it does not give me the desired results.

```
 RTRIM(avg(ProcTime)/3600) + ':'  + RIGHT(('0'+RTRIM(avg(MTD_ProcTime) % 3600) / 60),2)
```

Let's say I get 2:5 instead of 2:05, it drops the zero.  How do I get that zero in front of the 5 ?

Comment: Can you state what you're doing and that what 2:5 or 2:05 means. Also what does ProcTime & MTD_ProcTime contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
RTRIM(avg(ProcTime)/3600) + ':'  + RIGHT(('0'+RTRIM(avg(MTD_ProcTime) % 3600 / 60)),2)
```

I moved the `)` from after `3600` to after `60`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the two zeros in your `RIGHT(('00'+ ...` function, like this:

```
RTRIM(avg(ProcTime)/3600) + ':'  + 
RIGHT(('00'+RTRIM(avg(MTD_ProcTime) % 3600) / 60),2)
```

That way you end up with right 2 chars of 00N, or 0N.